# Consistency of multistep methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following problem:

> A linear multistep method is consistent of order p if and only if $\mu$=1 is a root of degree p of the function $\frac{\rho(\mu)}{ln(\mu)}=\sigma(\mu).$
>
> ($\rho(\mu)$ and $\sigma(\mu)$ being the first and second characteristic polynomial of the linear multistep method)

So I've already shown "$\Rightarrow$", but I have problems showing the other direction. So far I've got:

Let $\mu=1$ be a root of degree p of the function $\frac{\rho(\mu)}{ln(\mu)}=\sigma(\mu)$. Set $\mu=e^h$. Then we got that the function just now is equal to: $\frac{1}{h}\rho(e^h)-\sigma(e^h)$, which then has h=0 as a root of degree p. How do I continue from there? I appreciate any help.